# navigate through XML document with XMLpullParser

Tags: java, android

I am using the `XmlPullParser` to pull data from an **XML** document.  My **XML** document is structured like this:

```
<creature id="1">
<name>CreatureName</name>
<type>CreatureType</type>
<size>CreatureSize</size>
</creature>
<creature id="2">
<name>CreatureName</name>
<type>CreatureType</type>
<size>CreatureSize</size>
</creature>
<creature id="3">
<name>CreatureName</name>
<type>CreatureType</type>
<size>CreatureSize</size>
</creature>
```

My code is currently working if I only have one creature in my **XML** file.

I'm looking for a way to chose the creature based on the creature ID.  For example, if the ID was 2, then the `XMLPullParser` would only parse the **XML** under creature ID="2".

Here is my code so far:

```
xpp.next();
String elName = "";
int encounterId = 0; 
int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
    {

 if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT)
 {      
     System.out.println("START_DOCUMENT "+xpp.getName());
 }
 else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
 {
     if(encounterId >= 0) {
         if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("creature")) {
             System.out.println("inside while loop --- "+xpp.getName());
             try {
                 encounterId = Integer.parseInt(xpp.getAttributeValue(0));
                 System.out.println("attribute value = " + encounterId);
             } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                 Log.e("attribute value error", e.getMessage());
             }
             //DETERMINE ELEMENT NAME
         } else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
             System.out.println("inside while loop --- "+xpp.getName());
             elName = "name";
         } else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("type")) {
             elName = xpp.getName();
             elName = "type";
         } else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("size")) {
             elName = xpp.getName();
         elname = "size";
             }

 } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
     System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());

 } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
     //COLLECT DATA

     if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
        this.name = xpp.getText();
     } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("type"))  {
        this.race = xpp.getText();
     } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("size")) {
        this.gender = xpp.getText(); 
 }
eventType = xpp.next();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't xpp.next() inside while loop? There is no loop happening to read all the elements (if I understand your code correct).

Comment: oops forgot to paste that in...edited to show that.  Thanks for catching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use XPath for it

```
    XmlPullParser xpp = context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.zoo_table);
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    try {
        String askFor2 = "//creature[@ID='2']";
        NodeList creaturesNodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(askFor2, xpp, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        // here you have all such creatures - the list of one node in your case
```

Comment: XPath was introduced in SDK 8(2.2). If you have older Android you should find some jar for it. According to this site, there are some.

Comment: in the example code you wrote above, where would you use askFor2 ?  thanks

Comment: oh ok, I see.  So would I loop through this via a while loop as I do in my original code?

Comment: If you know there is only one item in the list, you could only check for the presence of the askFor2.item(0) by reading the askFor2.getLength()

Comment: Doesn't work. `XPath.evalute()` expects `InputSource` or `Node`. `XmlPullParser` is neither - so exception is thrown.

Comment: @HyBRiD Or Object. Look http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html. Maybe, you have some old Java?

Comment: @Gangnus yes but the object has to be of type `Node`. Check the source code [here](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/external/apache-xml/src/main/java/org/apache/xpath/jaxp/XPathImpl.java#215). Did you try to run this code?

Answer (score 1):

The XMLPullParser will always read through the entire document based on the current way you have your program coded. . If you only want to print out the details for the creature with id 2, you should make sure encounterId == 2 before you record the name, race, and gender of the creature inside of your TEXT event type if statement.

There is no way for the XMLPullParser to know that somewhere in teh document there is something with ID 2 and to just skip to it. This style of XML parsing reads through the XML document from the start until you decide to stop parsing.

**EDIT** 
More specific code

```
else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
     //COLLECT DATA
     if(encounterId == 2) {
        if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
            this.name = xpp.getText();
         } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("type"))  {
            this.race = xpp.getText();
         } else if(elName.equalsIgnoreCase("size")) {
            this.gender = xpp.getText(); 
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Oh ok, so if I determine the ID before I start the XMLPullParser, I can just do something like this? if(creatureID == 2) { //parse XML }

Comment: wait that wouldn't work because it would never reach that XML because creatureID would never be set to 2.

Comment: I edited my answer to more accurately show what you would need to do. Obviously, I am assuming you are trying to do much more than print out this information so I didn't address the other print statements.

Comment: So I am now determining and setting the ID before I run the code.  And I inserted the if(encounterId == 2) line.  The code runs through the XML, but it always sets the variables(this.name) to the last item listed in the XML file.  It doesn't matter what I set encounterId to.