# How to convert a XmlResourceParser to a org.w3c.dom.Document?

Tags: android, dom

In an Android app I'm wirting, I have an HTML-like document in the resources. Unfortunately, I retrieve it in an `XmlResourceParser` object (using `getResources().getXml(R.xml.texts)`, but I need to do significvant minipulation to it which I can only get in an `org.w3c.dom.Document` object. How can I convert it?

Comment: I was googling for this and found an identical SO question, which was answered by... me.  I'd forgotten all about it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36178928/4504191 Please upvote if you find it helpful.  Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36176740/get-org-w3c-dom-document-from-xmlresourceparser